# Request at localhost:/token from origin 'http://localhost:' has been blocked by CORS

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller

I have made a asp.net web api which works perfectly when i try to access it by making views inside the api itself. I have made a register, a login and a data page where you are redirected after login. where a table with some data is shown. this works perfectly through the api views itself. Now the problem that arises here is that if i try to register by adding another project into the solution that'll work flawlessly. but i cant seem to login. i get a bad blocked by cors error. even though i have enabled cors in the api project.

This is the jquery:

```
            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://localhost:58334/token',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    username: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                    password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                    grant_type: 'password'
                },

                success: function (response) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.access_token);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("userName", response.userName);
                    window.location.href = "Data.html";
                },

                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');
                }
            });
        });
```

The startup.auth.cs class:
    public partial class Startup
    {
        static Startup()
        {
            PublicClientId = "self";

```
        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }


    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);   
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

    }
```

The webapi.config register methof:

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
       config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

Comment: the error that i get is:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:58334/token' from origin 'http://localhost:52077' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Did you try adding default credentials instead of a username and password?

Comment: when i press the login button from the consuming webpage from another project the locahost:58334 /token link doesnt hit. it gives me cors error

Comment: i can share the whole project if you want in a zip file

Answer (score 0):

How you are accessing "localhost:5833" ?? did you hosted your client/app at webserver ??  if you are using file protocol "file:\" to access server resource you might get this cors error because of browser security. (for example double click to open the HTML file in browser is using a file:\ protocol)

Comment: i just run it from the button in vs. Both the projects are located in the same solution

Comment: i view the client page by right clicking it alongside also running the api

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15S4_8njitVP0tgC2aKDbsQNjnLa0H_br here is a link to the whole project. the user database is present inside of the project. i just need to get a way to login from the client application project